# Credit cards messages on AS400 DATAQ

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

how to export alerts messages from AS400 DATAQ once revived to PF table 
to be ready to send to remote oracle table

with consideration that the DATAQ delete the message once the last one received 
is it applicable to create trigger on the DATAQ to export the message content and create the table once the message received 
please help

Comment: Please rephrase topic, not specific enough

Comment: The need isn't clear. In general, for each entry that arrives, receive the DTAQ entry with the Receive Data Queue API, then write that data with whatever method you want to use to put a row into a table. What else is needed? (Why is a table needed at all?)

Comment: Related to E-Banking Message Alerts that we have messages send to DATAQ and we must be take the contents of message to cut steering by any method ; my issue how we can automate the process of dataq extraction. at the same time the new message delete the old one

Comment: That's mostly just (1) receive entry with API, (2) write entry record to database table, (3) go to step 1. What part isn't clear? What else is needed?

Comment: need to automate the processes started from message received to final step that is send the message content to data base table

Comment: It really depends on what language you are using. We need more information. If SQL, use an insert to add a record to the database. If RPG, you could use a write. Of course you should already know this. Please edit your question to be more clear. What language are you using. Where is the database. How are you connecting to the Oracle database?

Comment: Just I need to know (how to create trigger or listener for the Data queue by any language)

Answer (score 1):

Given followup replies in the comments, seems possible the inquiry might be resolved mostly, with use of the [Receive Data Queue (QRCVDTAQ) API](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/qrcvdtaq.htm); i.e. the arrival of a new message\entry on the Data Queue (DTAQ) *triggers* the receipt by the program requesting the API to await\receive that new message.  That feature is available via Java from a class of the JTOPEN\JT400 ToolBox [Programming->Java->IBM Toolbox for Java->IBM Toolbox for Java classes->Access classes->Data queues](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/dtaq.htm)

FWiW: Like other commenters to the OP, I can not figure out what is alluded by mention of a PF or Oracle; the OP text seems possibly to have been generated by a web language translator from non-English text to [seemingly incoherent] English, so if that is not how the text originated, then consider trying to rephrase [or rewrite] the text as one of the comments had suggested. Please understand I am not trying to taunt anyone about their skill with English by having made that statement; only trying to clarify why the request is made. Sometimes for programmers composing an OP, by writing what does occur or needs to occur, written procedurally and written in pseudo-code, can make the OP much clearer to more readers than can writing sentences and paragraphs.